# Use the subjective tag for subjective questions

Tags: discussion, questions, tags, retagging

IMO, all the question with subjective tone should be flagged as subjective.

It would make easier to filter questions when one want to answer subjective or non-subjective questions.

Answer (score 4):

A [subjective] tag would be a meta tag, and these are [explicitly discouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

In addition, please keep in mind that subjective questions themselves are iffy.  I highly recommend reading the following blog posts:

- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
- [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)

Comment: Subjective questions are tough, but if they meet the guidelines for a good subjective question, they can have quite a powerful impact.  I enjoy the great subjective questions.  They make me think and have helped me find ways to improve my skills, both here and in Programmers SE.

Comment: @jmort253, sure, they're iffy, but there are some pearls.  However, a meta tag won't help.

Comment: Agreed.  No point in a meta tag.  I was just saying that subjective questions can add a lot of value as long as the OP carefully words the question and follows the guidelines in the FAQ.  +1 for discouraging meta tag.

Answer (score 1):

Do we need subjective questions at all? What is the purpose of them? Stackexchange is not a blog, not a forum, and not an online book. It's a Q&A site, where I ask a question and get an answer. My purpose is not "to talk" here, but to get or give information.